# VRUNTIME variable maximum value in minutes / hours (CFS Scheduler)

Tags: linux, scheduling

VRUNTIME is described as the variable in the sched_entity structure that tracks time (nanoseconds).

1. is this a 64 bit value ? If so what is the maximum time in minutes / hours this variable can hold.
2. With the min_vruntime value, is it to be understood that any new task that is added to the run queue has its vruntime set to this variable ?

I am a bit confused and clarification of these points will be appreciated